# pentaho report designer : adding parameter

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

I'm trying to add a parameter on pentaho report designer and I don't quite understand one thing:
I have a table where there are information of clients over two months. So one person appears two times.
[image: example of the table]

And I want to make a parameter of month.
However when I set up the parameter by choosing month, on the selection window, it shows 03 04 03 04 and more.
All I want is one time of 03 and one time of 04.
I can't figure out where the prob is coming from.
Anyone has in idea please? Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is your SQL query for displaying month.
I assume you must be missing distinct clause.
If you are selecting 
select month from tablename then it will give your repeatative resulst instead use 
select distinct month from tablename.

Comment: @WorkingHard.., that's definitely the answer to ayay's problem--why not add an actual answer so that it can be accepted?

Comment: @ayay this has no relevance to Pentaho Report Designer. Your question is just a basic SQL question related to GROUP BY/DISTINCT

Comment: Indeed, I changed sql query and it works out as I want. thanks a lot guys :)))